# Selenium test's crashing on Jenkins because of virtual machine memory

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im testing some selenium test's in Jenkins and they are crashing, I read in a stackoverflow post that it is because Jenkins uses a virtual machine and it can be a memory problem, the solution is to use somethink like this: `chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')` but the problem is that I dont know where I should put this code in order to solve the problem, I dont know if I use the code on docker.compose or in the tests-selenium.side.

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

This is a chrome option, add this `(tests-selenium.side)` where you have `Options` instance.

You must have

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
```

written in your code somewhere.

Then **redeploy** your script in **Jenkins** **VM** and it should work.